# RShiny computation progress indicator

Tags: r, shiny, busyindicator

I made an RShiny app with a lengthy computation.

The lengthy computation leaves the screen at a standstill, and I am worried that either the computation came up blank, or that the connection timed out, or something else might have happened.

Is there a way to show an indicator (ie rotating hour glass, etc) on the screen to show the user that processing is ongoing.

Comment: Have a look at `withProgress()` ([here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html)) or `withSpinner()` from package [shinycssloaders](https://github.com/andrewsali/shinycssloaders)

Comment: remotes::install_github("dreamRs/shinybusy")

Answer (score 0):

You could add a progress bar. http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/Progress.html.

This might take a bit of refactoring, but it improves the UX and would give you an idea of where the failure is occurring(Connection, computation, etc.).