# RShiny read log file and show in UI while running a process

Tags: r, shiny

The question is similar to the below link but I would need to read a log file on a status button click(A simple text file which gets written with the progress messages from a process).

[RShiny computation progress indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852969/rshiny-computation-progress-indicator)

I have a `status` button in `UI.R`. and in `server.R` I have a `observeEvent(input$status, {` to observe the status button click.

This works fine when the page is not busy. ie. If i click `status` After `submit` process is completed and the page is sitting idle, then the event is triggered correct. But if the job from `submit` is still running, then `status` click doesn't work.

Code :

```
 observeEvent(input$status, {
    output$clog <- renderUI({
      invalidateLater(2000L)
      readlines(logfile())
    })
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title     = 'log'
      , easyClose = TRUE
      , footer    = NULL
      , size      = "l"
      , uiOutput("clog")
    ))
  })
```

In submit, I source other R script files. and inside the script file I am writing the progress to a log file. This is the file I am reading in `status` click.

Is there any way I can trigger the status click, before `submit` complete?

Comment: How can the app read a file which is not created yet? Do you mean that you "update" the file with `submit` and you want to read the not updated version of it?

Comment: @phago29. Log file is created and updated on  `submit` and want to read the same file in `status` click to see the progress. The problem is , the `status` button click event is not triggered. I think because the job submitted is still working.

Comment: Yes, since the file is updating at that moment, you cannot use the file. But the app may read the file if you assign it to another variable. I'm not sure about it but you can try something like `file <- logfile()` and then call `readlines(file)` inside `observeEvent`.

Comment: @phago29. reading the file is not the problem I am facing,. The `observeevent` is not getting triggered is the problem.